# ArrayList elemsts to be viewed evenly on the same view

Tags: java, android

I am trying to view list elements on the same view however 6 at a time. To start with, a cursor is called which in turn populates an array list with all the items.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            try {
                do {
                    items.add(ChecklistItem.fromCursor(cursor));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Then that list is given to an adapter, which in turn handles vieweing the items on the current view.

```
 if (items.size() > 0) {
            if (mAdapter == null)
            {
                mAdapter = new RecipeDetailAdapter(this, items, this);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
            else
            {
                mAdapter.updateItems(items);
            }
        }
```

On the view, there is a next button, which when clicked takes you to another view.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.next_button:
                startActivity(new Intent(RecipeDetailActivity.this, RecipeTasksActivity.class)
                .putExtra(RecipeTasksActivity.RECIPE_KEY, mRecipe.getRecipeId()));
                finish();
                break;
     }
}
```

At the moment the view shows whatever items are in the list, could be 10, 30, 50, etc.

What I am trying to achieve is, assuming the list has 18 items,  view the first 6 items in that list, then when the button "next" is clicked, view the other 6, and then when next is clicked, view the rest of the 6. Keeping in mind that I need to check if the list has 6 items or less, if less, view all of them, if more, spread them on two instances of the same view.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by using the OFFSET & LIMIT in your query.

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + ORDER_BY + " LIMIT 0, 20", NULL);
```

Note : On above 0 is your OFFSET & 20 is your limit. in your case LIMIT would be 6. You can maintain offset by `k * Limit` where k would your pager number.

Comment: True. That might work, in case I only want to view the first 6 items. But how can I keep track what I have selected and what is left to select?

Comment: Define one var called `page` and increment it by one when pressed next, decrements it by one when pressed previous.